# mysqli - Update integers

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there an easier way to UPDATE an integer value within a table by 1 without 'fetching/returning' the value?

I'm looking for something similar to `$i ++;`

```
$query = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE table SET col = ?");
$query->bind_param(++);
$query->execute();
```

Obviously the above wont work but that's sort of what I hope to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course:

```
$query = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE table SET col=col+1");
```